# Jenkins pipeline with parallel stages causes "process apparently never started" error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to set up a Jenkins pipeline (using the declarative syntax) that runs unit and feature tests on two separate, on-demand AWS EC2 instances. The pipeline works perfectly when run on a single instance and without the parallel stages. As soon as I switch to parallel stages, any shell script fails with this cryptic message:

> process apparently never started in
>   /home/admin/workspace/GSWebRuby_Test@tmp/durable-b0d8c4b4 (running
>   Jenkins temporarily with
>   -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true
>   might make the problem clearer)

I've googled extensively and came across several bug reports of the [Durable Task plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/durable-task-plugin) that appears to be responsible for this message. I'm using the latest version of the plugin v. 1.33 and none of the problems seem to apply to my case, e.g. failures on unusual architectures or when running Docker containers. I've also down- and re-upgaded the plugin (toggling between versions 1.30 and 1.33). Also, to re-iterate, `sh` commands work without issue when I don't use the `parallel` stages.

I've created a simplified pipeline to debug the problem. Note that the shell commands are also simple, e.g. "env | sort", or "pwd".

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  environment {
    DB_USER = credentials('db-user')
    DB_PASS = credentials('db-pass')
  }
  stages {
    stage('Setup'){
      failFast false
      parallel {
        stage('foo') {
          agent {
            label 'jenkins-slave-ondemand'
          }
          steps {
            echo 'In stage foo'
            sh 'env|sort'
          }
        }
        stage('bar') {
          agent {
            label 'jenkins-slave-ondemand'
          }
          steps {
            echo 'In stage bar'
            sh 'pwd'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the console output:

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $DB_PASS or $DB_USER
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Setup)
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] { (Branch: foo)
[Pipeline] { (Branch: bar)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (foo)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (bar)
[Pipeline] node
[Pipeline] node
Still waiting to schedule task
All nodes of label ‘jenkins-slave-ondemand’ are offline
Still waiting to schedule task
All nodes of label ‘jenkins-slave-ondemand’ are offline
Running on EC2 (Jenkins AWS EC2) - Jenkins slave (i-0982299c572100c71) in /home/admin/workspace/GSWebRuby_Test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
In stage foo
[Pipeline] sh
Running on EC2 (Jenkins AWS EC2) - Jenkins slave (i-092ecac8e6c257270) in /home/admin/workspace/GSWebRuby_Test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
In stage bar
[Pipeline] sh
process apparently never started in /home/admin/workspace/GSWebRuby_Test@tmp/durable-b0d8c4b4
(running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
Failed in branch foo
process apparently never started in /home/admin/workspace/GSWebRuby_Test@tmp/durable-b6cfcff9
(running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
Failed in branch bar
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code -2
Finished: FAILURE
```

Am I doing something wrong in the way I've set up the pipeline? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**:

After setting this `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS` `org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true`, I see this additional output:

```
In stage bar
[Pipeline] sh
nohup: failed to run command 'sh': No such file or directory
process apparently never started in /home/admin/workspace/GSWebRuby_Test@tmp/durable-099a2e56
```